# Child Component getting called when application loads

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have a component called cancellation that I want to call when a user clicks a button in the names component.  I do this by setting the loadCancellation flag to true when the Search button gets called.  And then in the cancellation component, I only show the html if loadCancellation is set to true.

However, in the developer tools, the cancellation component gets called first when the names component loads and also when the Search button gets clicked.

How do I prevent the cancellation component getting called when the names component loads?

I tried setting the loadCancellation flag to false in the names component constructor.  But the cancellation component still got raised.

I think this is happening because I'm setting the loadCancellation as an attribute to the component like below.

```
<app-cancellation [zipCode]="zipCodeVal" [lastName]="lastNameVal" [loadCancellation]="loadCancellation"></app-cancellation>
```

Here is the code:

names.component.html

```
<form class="body">
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="zipCodeVal" matInput placeholder="ZipCode" name="zipCode"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="lastNameVal" matInput placeholder="LastName" name="lastName"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSearch()">Search</button>
</form>
<app-cancellation [zipCode]="zipCodeVal" [lastName]="lastNameVal" [loadCancellation]="loadCancellation"></app-cancellation>
```

names.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-names',
  templateUrl: './names.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./names.component.css']
})
export class NamesComponent {
  private zipCode: string;
  private loadCancellation: boolean;

  constructor() {
    // this.loadCancellation = false;
  }
  onSearch() {
    this.loadCancellation = true;
    console.log("cancellation is: " + this.loadCancellation);
  }
}
```

cancellation.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="loadCancellation">
<p>
  ZipCode is: {{zipCode}} lastName is: {{lastName}}
</p>
</div>
```

cancellation.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerNameService } from '../customer-name.service';
import { CustomerName } from '../customer-name';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cancellation',
  templateUrl: './cancellation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cancellation.component.css']
})
export class CancellationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input('zipCode') zipCode: string;
  @Input('lastName') lastName: string;
  @Input('loadCancellation') 
  set loadCancellation(loadCancellation: boolean) {
    console.log("inside set cancellation");
    this.customerNameService
        .getCustomerNames(this.zipCode, this.lastName)
        .subscribe(data => {this.customerNames = data;})
  }
  customerNames: Array<CustomerName>

  constructor (private customerNameService: CustomerNameService) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // console.log(this.loadCancellation);


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component selector exists in a html template then it will created. On creation the inputs values will be passed along (true and false are just values here) and the `ngOnInit()` will be run.

If you only want the cancellation component to be created when `loadCancellation`is true then you could do something like this.

```
<app-cancellation *ngIf="loadCancellation" [zipCode]="zipCodeVal" [lastName]="lastNameVal"></app-cancellation>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Didn't realize I could add *ngIf like that in when creating the component.  Thank you!